An insane driver chasing a woman
This is a crime-horror-thriller movie .
Date : maybe 90's to 2004
Language : English.
Country : USA  
Story : An insane driver chasing a woman and wanted to kill her wherever she was, even indoors
Details :
It was a traffic jam on on highway when a woman turned her car in front of a truck , so the chase begun between that insane criminal driver and scared lady.
Furthermore, as revenge, the chase wasn't enough, he ran after her to her house to kill her, and her family, so he sneaked to the basement of the house, waiting the woman and her husband in the dark.

Possible duplicate of What's The Name Of That Movie?

no,no, it's another movie with different story

I think this might be Road Rage (1999)

Ellen Carson (Yasmine Bleeth) is a real estate agent who inadvertently cuts off a delivery truck driver while changing lanes on the freeway to hurry home. The truck driver turns out to be a disturbed man named Eddie Madden (Jere Burns), who proceeds to chase after Ellen in an effort to run her off the road. 
Ellen in fear calls the 1-800 number on the back of his truck and lodges a complaint, which causes Eddie to lose his job, and he (being a grieving husband and father who earlier lost his family to a car accident) sets out to destroy Ellen's family and soon becomes fixated on Ellen and her teenage stepdaughter Cynthia (Alana Austin) and plots to have them as replacement family, by removing the head of the house, Ellen's husband and Cynthia's father Jim Carson (John Wesley Shipp).
Wikipedia





yes it's him ^_^ many thanks Paulie_D
